# Authorization with passport in node.js and redis

Tags: node.js, redis, authorization, passport.js

I am doing classic authorization with **passport** module and **redis** as persistance for sessions in **node.js**.
Sessions are nicely saving to my redis after login and ttl of that session in redis is nicely updated when another request come after login etc.

What bothers me is when I manually delete session in redis (or before login when there are no session) other request (beside login) are passing normally. Shouldn't passport automatically respond as **unautorized** or we should do that manually somehow? In what part of code should I check if there is session in redis connected with cookie that I get in request.

Thanks,
Ivan

If someone need, here is my code:

```
// use local strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done) {

            var userPromise = userData.findByUsername(username);
            userPromise.success(function(user){
                if (!user) { 
                    return done(null, false);
                }
                if ( user.password != security.hash(user.salt, password) ){ // check password
                    return done(null, false);
                }
                var userCookie = {
                    id : user.id,
                    username : username
                }
                return done(null, userCookie);

            })
            .error(function(err){
                    return done(err);
            });
        }
    ));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        done(null, {id:id})
    });

// adding express middleware for passport and redis store
app.use(express.session({
        secret: "s0meR4nd0mT0k3n",
        store : new RedisStore({
            host : config.redis.host,
            port : config.redis.port
            //user : config.redis.username,
            //pass : config.redis.password
        }),
        cookie : {
            maxAge : 604800
        }
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
```